# Do un-awaited tasks always start when created via create_task?

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await

I'm trying to create a server, and I'm having difficulty understanding how using `create_task` starts a coroutine in motion. In the first test, `create_task` seems to start the task immediately. In the second test though, it doesn't seem to start it until it's awaited.

```
import asyncio

async def task_test():
    async def delayed_print(delay, message):
        await asyncio.sleep(delay)
        print(message)

    print_task = asyncio.create_task(delayed_print(2, "Hello"))
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print("World")
    await print_task

asyncio.run(task_test())
Hello
World
```

If `print_task` only started when `await print_task` was reached, "World\nHello" would have been printed instead.

---

The problem is, this seems to contradict the behavior I'm seeing with `AbstractServer`'s `serve_forever` function. If I setup a similar test for starting a server:

```
async def server_test():
    server: asyncio.AbstractServer = await asyncio.start_server(lambda r, w: print("conn"), "127.0.0.1", 5555)

    serve_task = asyncio.create_task(server.serve_forever())

    # await serve_task  # The pivotal part
    return server
```

The server only accepts incoming connections when the (currently commented) `await` line executes; suggesting `serve_forever` requires `await`ing to work properly.

Evidence:

```
asyncio.run(server_test())  # With "await serve_task" commented out
# Returns

# --- In another REPL

rdr, wtr = asyncio.run(asyncio.open_connection("127.0.0.1", 5555))
Traceback (most recent call last):
    # Truncated - It's very long
    raise OSError(err, f'Connect call failed {address}')
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 10061] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 5555)
```

It errors out due to the client being unable to connect to the server.

If I uncomment out that line though:

```
asyncio.run(server_test())  # With "await serve_task" executing
# Never returns

# --- In another REPL

rdr, wtr = asyncio.run(asyncio.open_connection("127.0.0.1", 5555))

(rdr, wtr)
(<StreamReader transport=<_SelectorSocketTransport fd=1064>>, <StreamWriter transport=<_SelectorSocketTransport fd=1064> reader=<StreamReader transport=<_SelectorSocketTransport fd=1064>>>)
```

It connects successfully ("conn" is printed out in the server REPL).

Can anybody explain why `serve_forever` is only allowing the server to accept connected when it's awaited? I would rather not need to explicitly `await` the `serve_task`. Why?:

- I want to understand why there's a difference between these two fairly similar bits of code so I can avoid future pitfalls, but mostly...
- Because I don't want to have to `await` `serve_forever`. That will create an effectively infinite blocking call preventing the server from doing anything new. Ideally, I'd like to be able to start the server in a REPL, and send commands to the server locally to carry out actions. With how it is right now, the REPL becomes blocked as soon as I start the server. The only workaround I've come up with is pre-creating tasks I'll want to run and delaying them, then giving them and `serve_forever` to `gather`. Something like:

  ```
  asyncio.gather(server.serve_forever(),
                 some_delayed_task,
                 some_other_delayed_task)
  ```

Any clarity here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to `await` the result of `create_task(serve_forever())`. You do, however, need to `await` *something*. In `asyncio`, only one thing can happen at a time, and it's only possible to switch between tasks with `await`. Until you reach an `await`, the `serve_forever` task isn't actually running.

The problem you're seeing in the REPL is that because the REPL is not implemented in terms of `asyncio`, so while you're sitting at the repl prompt no `asyncio` tasks can be run. Try using [`aioconsole`](https://aioconsole.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) instead of the standard REPL.

Comment: Ah, so in the first, it's printing first because it's been allowed to run by `await asyncio.sleep(5)`. If I add an `await asyncio.sleep(10)` after creating `serve_task` though, it still doesn't seem to have run.

Comment: OH! Ha. It does run `serve_forever`. The problem is, `run` cancels all pending tasks like `serve_forever` when it exits. If I connect the client during the sleep before returning, it works.

Answer (score 0):

@Ben's right, but I just to elaborate on what happened here because it's interesting.

The first example works because `await asyncio.sleep(5)` passes off control and allows the `delayed_print` task to run.

The second example doesn't work because I never pass off control using `await` to let any other tasks run. Seemingly, the solution to this then would be to add a `sleep` or something to let other tasks run:

```
async def server_test():
    server: aio.AbstractServer = await aio.start_server(lambda r, w: print("conn"), "127.0.0.1", 5555)

    serve_task = aio.create_task(server.serve_forever())
    await aio.sleep(10)
    return server
```

I thought that surely during the 10-second passoff, `serve_forever` would have had a chance to run. After the 10 seconds though, I still couldn't connect.

It turns out, `serve_forever` *was* running, and I *could* connect, but only during the 10 second window. The problem is, `asyncio.run` cancels all [running tasks when it exits](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7e18deef652a9d413d5dbd19d61073ba7eb5460e/Lib/asyncio/runners.py#L46). In this case, that meant `serve_forever` was being cancelled. If I connect during the `sleep` though, it's fine:

```
async def server_test():
    server: aio.AbstractServer = await aio.start_server(lambda r, w: print("conn"), "127.0.0.1", 5555)

    aio.create_task(server.serve_forever())
    await aio.sleep(10)
    return server

server = aio.run(server_test())

# --- Quickly switch to other REPL

rdr, wtr = aio.run(aio.open_connection("127.0.0.1", 5555))

# "conn" gets printed in server REPL

(rdr, wtr)
(<StreamReader transport=<_SelectorSocketTransport fd=988>>, <StreamWriter transport=<_SelectorSocketTransport fd=988> reader=<StreamReader transport=<_SelectorSocketTransport fd=988>>>)
```

In "real code", `run` ending and killing tasks shouldn't be a problem. My example was too simple and contrived to be useful unfortunately.